# Material UI/React - helper text not showing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Within my login react component, I'm trying to show a 'wrong credentials' error within my helper text - but upon entering false credentials, no text appears. Any suggestions as to why? At the moment I'm pushing an error message into an array, assigning that error to state, and then referencind that state in my helperText prop. Here's the code from my login component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import axios from 'axios'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import {auth} from 'firebase/app'


class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errors:[]
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }



  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { email, password } = this.state
    const { history } = this.props
    const errorLog = []
    this.setState({
      errors: errorLog
    })
    auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        history.push('/gigregister')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if(err.code = 'auth/wrong-password'){
         errorLog.push('Wrong credentials, please try again')
         console.log(`this is error state ${this.state.errors}`)
        }
      })
  }

  render() {
  
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <Header />
        </div>
        <div className ='gig-button'>
        <Link to="/Homepage" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
         <Button>Gigs this week</Button>
        </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="login-main">
          <div className="login">
            <h4>Venue login</h4>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
                placeholder="Enter email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <TextField
                placeholder="Enter password"
                id="password"
                name="password"
                error ={this.state.errors ? true : false}
                helperText = {this.state.errors}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <div className="button">
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <Link to="/venueregister" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
            <Button>Register a venue</Button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with your condition statement

```
if(err.code = 'auth/wrong-password'){
```

I think you meant to compare these values e.g., `==` or `===`.

Regarding the errors not showing up

> At the moment I'm pushing an error message into an array, assigning
> that error to state

You are not setting the state after pushing to `errorLog` array - just update the state after you've pushed to it.

```
.catch((err) => {
  if(err.code === 'auth/wrong-password'){
    errorLog.push('Wrong credentials, please try again')
    this.setState({
      errors: errorLog
    });
  }
})
```